# How to split pane in jQuery Layout plugin?

Tags: jquery, layout

I am using the jQuery Layout plugin to create a page with north, south, west, east and center pane. I'd like to split - after the layout is initiated - the west pane into two panes (west-north and west-south) for example.

But I didn't find any functions in the API to split a pane! Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested panes. The plugin supports unlimited nesting through childOptions. http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/nested_simple.html

I'd suggest naming the child panes uniquely.

```
   <div id="mainContainer">
        <iframe class="ui-layout-center" id="someiframecontent-right">Center Right content</iframe>
        <div class="ui-layout-west">
            <div class="ui-layout-childsouth">North West content </div>
            <div class="ui-layout-childcenter">South west content </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#mainContainer').layout({
            west__minSize: 100,
            west__size: 0.5,
            west__maxSize: 0.9,
            center__minSize: 100,
            center__size: 0.5,
            center__maxSize: 0.9,
            livePaneResizing: true,
            west__childOptions: {
                center__paneSelector: '.ui-layout-childcenter',
                center__minSize: 100,
                center__size: 0.5,
                center__maxSize: 0.9,
                south__paneSelector: '.ui-layout-childsouth',
                south__minSize: 100,
                south__size: 0.5,
                south__maxSize: 0.9,
                livePaneResizing: true
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Remember that center pane is always necessary (including in the child panes), as it's required to fill up the remaining spaces left over by other panes.

Comment: OK I get the child options. but then if you want to call a function on the child option like sizePane how do you reference west childoption south. So layoutManager.sizePane('west.south',200); does not work it states pane name incorrect.  All I get is LAYOUT ERROR - Invalid pane-name